# How to use DynamoDB Fine-Grained Access Control when end-users access via API gateway lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I've been attempting to use Fine-Grained access control to limit End-User access to DynamoDB but not having luck. While there's documentation out there to use Fine-Grained access control if users connect directly to DynamodDB, it's not so clear to me how this works if users connect to DynamoDB via an API gateway with Lambda.

**Flow**

User > API Gateway > Lambda > DynamoDB

1. Users authenticate with Cognito User Pools and send CRUD requests to an API gateway.
2. The API gateway uses Cognito Authorizer so that only authenticated users can interact with the APIs.
3. The API Gateway sends the event to a Lambda called list.
4. The Lambda queries DynamoDB using an execution role with AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess.

**The problem**

User1 can perform CRUD operations on User2's lists so I need to restrain each user to their own records, Fine-Grained Access control sounds like what I should use. Following a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-fine-grained-authorization-using-amazon-cognito-user-pools-groups/), I configured a Cognito Identity Pool for my Cognito User Pool, and created a the IAM role "EndUser-Role" with the following policy attached. This will get applied to all authenticated users via Cognito group:

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb: us-west-2:123456789111:table/lists"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}"
                    ]
                }
```

**My dynamodb table items looks like so**

```
{
  userId (Partition Key): User1
  listName: "User1-List"
}
{
  userId (Partition Key): User2
  listName: "User2-List"
}
```

**Testing with Postman**

GET: https://xyz.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/list?listName=User2-List

1. Keeping the Lambda Execution Role as is with AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess, I'm still able to query for User2's list when send an API call with User1's access_token. Fine-Grained access control isn't working.
2. Changing the Lambda Execution to be the same as the EndUser-Role, I get 502 error when querying for any list with User1's access_token. CloudWatch logs show:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetItem operation: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789111:assumed-role/EndUser-role/list-lambda is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:123456789111:table/lists because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:GetItem action
```

1. Is it not possible to use Fine-Grained access control since my users are don't touch dynamoDB directly?
2. If it is possible, what am I missing? Isn't the identity that missing passed with the access_token?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you will have to assume the role from the Cognito authorized user role. You do so by calling `sts assume_role` API.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

This AWS documentation outlines the steps necessary to fulfill your use case: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-user-pool-group